# Magento 2 User Permission Denied for Admin user

Tags: magento2, admin, permissions, user-roles, admin-user

I was creating user roles & permission as an admin in Magento 2, then I mistakenly denied myself permission to add roles and permission. Now It's showing "Access denied". I can't add or change my roles, and I know this is not an error or bug but a silly mistake from me. Please, how can go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Please create new admin user by command line and then assign role to existing user.

```
$ bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="newadmin" --admin-password="yourpassword" --admin-email="mail@example.com" --admin-firstname="newAdmin" --admin-lastname="newAdmin"
```

Comment: thank you for the response, do I have to assign the role using command line too?